# Order of "I", "my wife", "you" that must be followed by "were"

Tags: word-order, pronouns

In one of my exams, I had a multiple choice question and I had to choose the correct option.

> Question: **Please try to remember when `I, you and my wife` were talking there.**
>
> Options:
>
> - you, I and my wife
> - I, my wife and you
> - you, my wife and I
> - No correction.

**Which would be correct in this case? And why?**

Edit: This question appears [here](https://myexaminer.net/Argues/view/438697984) and they have marked the third option as correct answer. It may or may not be correct.

Comment: Idiomatically, regardless of the sequence, most people today would use ***me*** rather than ***I*** here. You probably wouldn't mention your wife before yourself or the addressee, but other than that it's up to you whether you identify yourself before the addressee. *Remember when **you and me and my wife** had a "three-in-a-bed" romp?*

Comment: (If that came in a "multiple-choice question", it's a complete garbage test. Don't bother with it.)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think you are correct because you are (probably) a native English speaker. However, in the exam they are (maybe) old school and so I have to stick with one of those options, no way out, else I don't get the job. :-D I thought it has something to do with"you" in the end.

Comment: Yes, the example question is not natural at all. Very clumsily worded, perhaps the verb *reminded* was used instead? “Please remind me the last time, you *and* my wife and I were talking about it”

Comment: Definitely need to retrace/reproduce the original question.

Comment: https://myexaminer.net/Argues/view/438697984 Was it this question? Note the misspelling of **explanation** in *No Explanaiton, Give your best explanaiton*

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ah yes, exactly. That question. Shall I reproduce it?

Comment: Yes, do that, before anyone posts an answer.

Comment: It's not a question of "old school". I'm just as much at home reading Victorian novels as modern texts. The test-setters are simply not competent.

Comment: In my opinion 'most people' would be wrong to use 'me'! You wouldn't say 'Do you remember when me was talking?".

Comment: @Kate: I think [*that is an example of hypercorrection*.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1051/2637) As pointed out in that ELU answer, the fact that ***You and me are going to the store*** is in principle "incorrect" is really beside the point - ***it's very common in contemporary spoken English.*** So much so that (for me, at least) using ***You and I*** in such contexts is "marked".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - You'll also hear a lot of people using **myself** in this situation. It's a pet peeve of mine and I *hate* it, but the use of the reflexive pronoun to avoid this I/me controversy seems to be increasingly common.

Comment: @CanadianYankee: Oh dear! You won't like *my* approach then! Although in my "natural" register I'd almost always use ***me*** in such contexts, I freely admit that *sometimes* I'll deliberately use the reflexive form if I think whoever I'm talking to might view my natural usage as "ignorant, uneducated" (I normally avoid "**I**" because to me that's a bit "la-di-dah"! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I disagree that this example is hypercorrection. The rule I always follow is to use the form that would be appropriate if 'I' was the _only_ person being referred to.

Comment: @Kate: Yes, I know that's what you think. That's why I "tempered" my earlier comment by saying **(for me, at least)**. I still think it's a garbage test, and you having flagged up that "Explanaiton" typo leads me to suppose that at least we can agree on *that* point! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica That was Mari-Lou, not me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no grammar rule here.

There is a rule of etiquette to place others before yourself. This rule of etiquette would mean that "you and I" is preferred to "I and you". The rule was "others first, self last". In formal speech it is usually observed.

<sub>When I was actually taught this rule, in year 1, many years ago, I was actually taught that the order had to be "God first, others next, self last".  This kind of rule comes from a different age</sub>

Now here someone seems to have extended that rule to say "Others first, family next, self last", and so the order should be "You, my wife and I". Such a rule may be invented by speakers of languages that have more clearly defined hierarchies of honorific and humble language than English,(Japanese comes to mind).

How important is this?  Not very important. It doesn't affect comprehension. Many native speakers don't follow the etiquette rule anyway, and many use a different rule for the pronoun "me" or "I" in compound subjects.

I'd recommend using "You, my wife, and I" in particularly polite or formal contexts (or when doing an MC test to get a new job).  In many other situations, you can apply a different rule: "Use 'I' when the subject is singular first-person" In this case, the subject is a phrase consisting of three people, so it isn't singular first person. Applying this rule gives "I was..." but "You and me were...".

In the exact context I'd prefer:

> Please try to remember when we were talking with my wife.

And note that this is a very strange request to make. It sounds as if you are judging someone on their failure to remember the conversation.  Like a police officer interviewing a witness, but why would the witness have been talking with the police officer's wife?.  It's very odd.